# Best strategy for Devise + Omniauth signin/up via API which doesn't provide email?

Tags: oauth, devise

Is there a a best considered pattern/strategy, or what are the best options, for signup & signin of users through Oauth via an API (Flickr in this case) which doesn't provide email in the callback, when using Devise for authentication which depends upon email (and password) for user authentication?